# React Router's useLoaderData Console Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

When I try using the `useLoaderData` hook from `react-router-dom`, it has been giving me the same error

> Uncaught Error: useLoaderData must be used within a data router.  See
> https://reactrouter.com/routers/picking-a-router.

no matter what change I make in the `Home` Component, so that made me guess the issue is not from there.

This is what my Main.jsx looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

My App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home, { homeLoader } from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'
import GlobalLayout from './GlobalLayout'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<GlobalLayout />}>  
          <Route index element={<Home />} loader={homeLoader} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

I think everything in my `Home.jsx` is fine

I have tried checking out the documentation attached to the error and its not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the RRDv6.4 Data APIs a data router must be used. See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router).

Use the `createBrowserRouter` utility to create a Data router. The created `router` object is passed to the `RouterProvider` component. Any routes and components that you want or need to use the Data APIs necessarily need to be declared here at build time as part of the data router creation.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Routes
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home, { homeLoader } from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import GlobalLayout from './GlobalLayout';

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<GlobalLayout />}>  
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} loader={homeLoader} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

const App = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default App;
```

Main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

- [createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)
- [RouterProvider](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider)
- [createRoutesFromElements](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-routes-from-elements)